# Network interface binder

Tags: windows, networking, gui

For a couple of purposes I need to bind Windows or some particular apps to use only a specific network interface. For example when my computer is connected by both WiFi and Ethernet, I want to choose which network interface to be used by Windows or apps to connect with.

So far after some googling, I have found a command line based tool for binding apps to a network interface. It is [ForceBindIP](http://www.howtogeek.com/117890/how-to-force-an-application-to-use-a-specific-network-card/).

But doing such interface switching for app by app seems to be difficult specially by a command line tool. So I come here for asking a GUI based app for this purpose.